# How to increase dimension of tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, tf.keras

I need to increase the dimension of a tensor from 3D to 4D because the `tf.image.extract_patches` takes input images which is a 4-D Tensor with shape [batch, in_rows, in_cols, depth], where I think depth is for rgb images but what I'm using is greyscale images which produce 3D tensors and in turn throws error in the extract_patches function.  So I want to increase the tensor dimension without any changes to its values.

The function works fine when I tried it with rgb image but when the same image is run in greyscale, it throws error.

Comment: If you are using Tensorflow, consider use the `tf.expand_dims`. Check more details here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims. (Or you can list your code snippet so that we can better help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to increase the dimension of a tensor in tensorflow, without repeating values:

```py
# a. using tf.expand_dims with axis as the last one
image_rgb = tf.expand_dims(image_grayscale, axis=-1)

# b. using slicing but with tf.newaxis at the desired position (last dim in this case)
image_rgb = image_grayscale[..., tf.newaxis]
```